# Wordpress rewrite rules causing 302 redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have started working on a site for a client that is on an old version Wordpress (3.2.1). The first task is to upgrade to the latest version of Wordpress (5.4.2). It being on version 3.2.1, I have to manually perform the upgrade. I have a staging site set up on a subdomain on the server as well as a local environment set up in a virtual machine.

This site makes use of rewrite rules to serve up its templates. There is a class called: `WordpressEndpointController` which creates custom rewrite rules for the different routes in the application. The class is as follows:

```
class WordpressEndpointController {
    protected $endpoint;
    protected $rule;
    protected $query;
    
    protected $callback;
    
    protected $flush;
    
    public static $message = "Initialized";
    
    public function __construct( $endpoint, $callback, $flush = false ) {
        $this->endpoint = $endpoint;
        $this->rule     = "{$endpoint}/?\$";
        $this->flush    = $flush;
        
        $this->callback = $callback;
        
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( &$this, 'addRule' ) );
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( &$this, 'testMatch' ) );
    }
    
    public function flagFlush() {
        $this->flush = true;    
    }
    
    public function addRule() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        
        $regex = $this->rule;
        
        $redirect = "index.php?";
        $wp_rewrite->add_rule( $regex, $redirect, 'top' );
        if ( $this->flush ) $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
    
    public function testMatch() {
        global $wp;
        $match = $wp->matched_rule;
        global $wp_rewrite;
        
        if ( $match == $this->rule ) {
            $this->onMatch();
            exit;
        }
    }
    
    public function onMatch() {
        call_user_func( $this->callback );
    }
}
```

This class is initialized in the theme's `functions.php` file for each endpoint like so:

```
$AccountEndpoint = new WordpressEndpointController( 'account', array( 'AccountController', 'processRequest' ), true );
```

Then in `.htaccess` at the root of the project we have the following (changed out actual domain for `example.com`):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

When a User navigates to an endpoint the URL would be something like: `/account/?action=contact`.
So when a request comes through, and the `template_redirect` action occurs, the `EndpointController` class will test if there is a match on one of the rewrite rules created and if there is it will call the callback passed through when each `EndpointController` was instantiated. Those callbacks do different things, but essentially they examine the query string passed and will call `wp_redirect`.

I've performed the manual update and in the subdomain I am getting: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. It looks like the application hits an endpoint and redirects back to the endpoint which redirects to the same endpoint until the browser stops this cycle.

Request Headers for one of these requests look like this:

```
Request URL: http://staging.example.com/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

When setting up the staging site on the subdomain I have changed the `.htaccess` `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]` to: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} staging\.example\.com [NC]` and: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]` to: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.example.com/$1 [R,L]`.

I have been able to navigate through the site on a subdomain in localhost (`staging.localhost`), but only if I change the `wp_option` `home` to be `http://example.com` which would be incorrect for a subdomain on localhost. I would think this value should be: `http://staging.localhost`.

One question that I have is: has anything major changed in the way Wordpress handles rewrite rules from 3.2.1 to the latest: 5.4.2? Is there something in the way that these endpoints are set up and the way that Wordpress handles the rewrites clashing with the `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess`? I have been working at this for a few days now and am struggling to understand what is happening here. I would be very grateful for any help, or insight anyone might be able to offer. Please let me know if I can offer more info that would be helpful in solving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: What might help to get in the right direct. Use a commandline util like curl or a rest client and look for a header “X-Redirect-By: WordPress" this way u know if ngnix is doing it or wordpress..

Comment: Further look at the Location: header and compare it to the actual requested url..  that might give u an insight

Comment: Also if you have WP Cli .. try `wp rewrite list` this shows all rewrite rules.. allows you to find conflicted rules

Comment: For one example, when requesting: `http://staging.example.com/account/?action=contact` the `Location` header in the response is: `http://staging.example.com/?action=contact`,  so it has dropped the `/account` part of the URI.